# How to install Munin

Tags: software-installation, monitoring

I need to install [Munin](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/tools-munin) on Ubuntu 12.04 for testing purposes. This is my first Munin installation and I have no idea how to get this done. I followed some tutorials, but the lack of instructional flow makes it very hard for me.

If someone out there has installed the Munin, please provide the steps.

What are the things that need to be installed?

Is there **Server Client** configuration involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munin is available in the repositories and can be installed through software center.

The Munin-node daemon must be running on the computers that you want to monitor.  Munin master is five other programs for gathering an displaying data depending on what you want.  Type:

```
man munin
```

for more information on these master programs and information on how to get to the man pages for each.

If you're still at a loss you should probably use the Manin FAQ, wiki, and how-to pages first:

[Munin - how to get help](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToGetHelp)

[Wikipedia information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munin_%28network_monitoring_application%29)

[Munin home page](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

Comment: Thanks dear, I will follow these links and will accept the solution  ,n will give u the update very soon

Comment: I hope this contributor wasn't holding their breath for you to "accept the solution" @OmiPenguin

Comment: :) it's been a very very long time. Need to review all the questions. But Thanks for notifying me